# [R]: using character as argument in a function

Tags: r, function, character

I've just a simple question regarding to case, that I want to use a character as an argument of a self created function.

I have three time series sets. Lets say a_ts, b_ts and c_ts and I want to merge a or b with c, depending on the funcion Input.

```
foo <-function(type){
   total_series <- rbind(type_ts,c_ts)
   return(total_series)
}
```

with type as type="a",  type="b".

Lets say I dont want to change the character names. How can I solve the Problem, that a isnt printed in quotes in the function.

I want  rbind(a_ts,c_ts) or rbind (b_ts,c_ts) without the quotes around my character argument.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `as.name("x")` gives you `x` ,`noquote("x") gives you `x` so technically you must tell what you need. Also remember if you have to input `type` then you will need to have `rbind(as.name(paste0(type,"_ts")),c_ts)`

Comment: I need the first one. a_ts or b_ts should be the solution. The quotes around a/b should be eliminated. It doesnt work with that because the series are in a xts Format. the error is object is not a Matrix.

Comment: Sorry, Idont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, something like this is what you need:

```
foo <- function(obj1, type) {
  obj2 <- paste0(type, "_ts")
  total_series <- rbind(obj1, get(obj2, envir = .GlobalEnv))
  return(total_series)
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but since Vala always wants to combine with his 
 _c_ts_ variable, I would simplify this way:
`foo <- function(type) {
  rbind(get(paste0(type, "_ts"), envir=globalenv()), c_ts)
}`